# How can I modify a loop that gets the daily pivots (highs/lows) of stock price to also get the weekly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily stock price high, low, close data in a pandas data frame. It looks like this. You can ignore the close column:

```
date            high        low         close
2003-03-10      16.3000     15.7100     1.1236
2003-03-11      15.7500     15.0000     1.1071
2003-03-12      15.5100     14.9000     1.0757
2003-03-13      16.5700     15.2500     1.1607
2003-03-14      16.9500     16.3900     1.1821
2003-03-17      18.0900     15.6600     1.2857
2003-03-18      19.1800     18.0700     1.3393
2003-03-19      19.5800     18.7000     1.3743
```

I have written a loop to get the pivots (highs/lows), similar to this graphic (except I am using highs and lows only, rather than the closing price, and don't care if the high is the next day or days later): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYXR6.png. I am then checking the pivots to see whether the last high pivot is higher than the previous high pivot and the last low pivot is higher than the previous low pivot (higher highs, higher lows; or the opposite)

So this data is daily stock price data and my loop is below (I am not sure if there is a better way to do this with Pandas, as I am new to Python). I was wondering how I could modify it to also return weekly pivots (i.e. is the low of last WEEKLY low higher than the previous weekly low and is the last weekly high higher than the previous weekly high, or the opposite). I would like to do it with monthly as well, but if I know how to do weekly, I can figure out monthly. That said, if there is a better way to do all this with Pandas, I'd be very interested.

Thanks for your help!

```
ltemp = [data.iloc[0].high, data.iloc[0].low]
LPIV = []
htemp = [data.iloc[0].high, data.iloc[0].low]
HPIV = []

trend_score = 0
trend_list = []
trend_length_list = []

trend_dir = 0
trend_length = 0

#data is my dataframe
for i, row in data.iterrows():
        # if the row sets a new pivot and confirms the last pivot in one days data, handle for that
        if ltemp and row.low < ltemp[1] and row.high > ltemp[0]:
            ltemp = [ltemp[0], row.low]
            LPIV.append(ltemp[1])
            htemp = [row.high, row.low]
            ltemp = []
        elif htemp and row.high > htemp[0] and row.low < htemp[1]:
            htemp = [row.high, htemp[1]]
            HPIV.append(htemp[0])
            ltemp = [row.high, row.low]
            htemp = []

        # If row closes higher than the high of the lowest low. confirm it as a pivot
        elif ltemp and row.high > ltemp[0]:
            LPIV.append(ltemp[1])
            htemp = [row.high, row.low]
            ltemp = []

        # If row closes lower than the low of the highest high. confirm it as a pivot
        elif htemp and row.low < htemp[1]:
            HPIV.append(htemp[0])
            ltemp = [row.high, row.low]
            htemp = []

        # if row moves higher or lower than temp high or low, adjust pivot
        elif ltemp and row.low < ltemp[1]:
            ltemp = [row.high, row.low]
        elif htemp and row.high > htemp[0]:
            htemp = [row.high, row.low]

        if trend_dir == 1 and row.close < last_trend_change[1]:
                trend_length = 0
        elif trend_dir == -1 and row.close > last_trend_change[3]:
                trend_length = 0

        if len(HPIV) == 2 and len(LPIV) == 2:
            if LPIV[0] <= LPIV[1] and HPIV[0] < HPIV[1]:
                if trend_dir == 1:
                    trend_length+=1
                else:
                    trend_dir = 1
                    trend_length=1
                last_trend_change = [LPIV[0], LPIV[1], HPIV[0], HPIV[1]]
            elif LPIV[1] < LPIV[0] and HPIV[1] <= HPIV[0]:
                if trend_dir == -1:
                    trend_length-=1
                else:
                    trend_dir = -1
                    trend_length=-1
                last_trend_change = [LPIV[0], LPIV[1], HPIV[0], HPIV[1]]

            if not htemp:
                LPIV.pop(0)
            else:
                HPIV.pop(0)


        trend_list.append(trend_dir)
        trend_length_list.append(trend_length)

    return trend_list, trend_length_list
```

EDIT:
I hope my code doesn't overcomplicate it. Basically, I need to run my same loop, but instead of the row being iterated containing 1 day of data (which is what the row actually contains), it needs to contain 5 days that are Mon-Fri (one trading week). That means the high is whatever the highest point was during the week, the low the lowest point in the week, the close is the close price on Friday. Maybe I need a separate loop for this and some pandas function to combine rows in that way?